# Can I delete all datas in path through HTTP DELETE request massage?

Tags: javascript, http, message, http-delete

```
postLectureKeywords({
    Id,
    Keywords,
  }) {
    return http.post(`/ids/${Id}/keywords`, {
    data: Keywords,
  });
}
```

Using the JavaScript code above, I put data called "Keywords" on the server.

The 'Keywords' that I want to put on the server is the list of dictionary data.

```
{key: "a", weight: 1}, {key: "b", weight: 12}, ...
```

The above http.post statement works normally and I can see that the data comes in as follows.

```
[{id: 2, key: "a", weight: 1}, {id: 2, key: "b", weight: 12}, … ]
```

Can I delete all of the above data at once using DELETE query?

```
http.delete(`/ids/${Id}/keywords/`);
```

This code does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you have to write the server-side code which processes the DELETE request to do that.